# Simple Php and Mysql Image Uploader

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a very basic image uploader script. Just one that uploads the image to a folder and stores the filename in a mysql database.

Is there any small easy to intergrate scripts anyone know of?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial does what you want http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/Upload_file_sql.htm in addition stores some extra metadata in the same table (employee details) along with the filename (photo)

Comment: Good starting point ... but nothing in that tutorial related to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Yes - quite so - and an important point - the questioner did ask for something very basic, however The next step would be to use a well known ORM framework - these usually deal with that sort of issue without  you having to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Images can be saved as blob types in a database

1. You have to create a form with a browse button (google it)
2. You have to create your table with the a field of type blob

That's it.